# jQuery animte position left top with hover

Tags: jquery

basically when I hover normally over the box it moves and goes back to the position but when you hover fast several times box goes backwards and loses position, any idea why? Thanks!

Also I need to grab current div position so im using `$(this)` when hover.

here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/JdMqM/1/

html:

```
<div class="box_wrap">
    <div class="box">
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.box_wrap {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
}

.box {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

js:

```
$('.box').hover(

  function(){
    var h = $(this).height();
    var w = $(this).width();
    var t = $(this).position().top;
    var l = $(this).position().left;

    $(this).animate({
      'width': w + 20 + 'px',
      'height': h + 20 + 'px',
      'left': l + 20,
      'top': t + 20
    }, { duration: 200, queue: false });
  },

  function(){
    var h = $(this).height();
    var w = $(this).width();
    var t = $(this).position().top;
    var l = $(this).position().left;

    $(this).animate({

      'width': w - 20 + 'px',
      'height': h - 20 + 'px',
      'left': l - 20,
      'top': t - 20
    }, { duration: 200, queue: false });
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are measuing the size and position while the object is being animated. Measure once then use those values.

```
var h = $('.box').height();
var w = $('.box').width();
var t = $('.box').position().top;
var l = $('.box').position().left;

$('.box').hover(

  function(){

    $(this).animate({
      'width': w + 20 + 'px',
      'height': h + 20 + 'px',
      'left': l + 20,
      'top': t + 20
    }, { duration: 200, queue: false });
  },

  function(){
    $(this).animate({

      'width': w + 'px',
      'height': h + 'px',
      'left': l ,
      'top': t 
    }, { duration: 200, queue: false });
  }
);
```

If you need to measure the current size each time you hover, you should stop the animation before taking the measurements.

```
$('.box').hover(

  function(){

    $(this).stop(false, true)

    var h = $(this).height();
    var w = $(this).width();
    var t = $(this).position().top;
    var l = $(this).position().left;

    $(this).stop().animate({
      'width': w + 20 + 'px',
      'height': h + 20 + 'px',
      'left': l + 20,
      'top': t + 20
    }, { duration: 200, queue: false });
  },

  function(){

    $(this).stop(false, true)

    var h = $(this).height();
    var w = $(this).width();
    var t = $(this).position().top;
    var l = $(this).position().left;

    $(this).animate({

      'width': w - 20 + 'px',
      'height': h - 20 + 'px',
      'left': l - 20,
      'top': t - 20
    }, { duration: 200, queue: false });
  }
);
```